# How to get back to the current window from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

In my **macOS** application, I am following a OAuth-Login procedure.
I am authenticating successfully by receiving a code within a url through my custom url, with which I already can get hold of an access_token.
I start the login procedure with the simple click of a button in a `ViewController`.

The system I log in to then answers with my registered custom url scheme, providing me with a code I have to then use to get an `access_token` with `POST` request. This access_token than can be used to make api calls.

My Problem now is that lacking knowledge of how to implement other techniques, I am currently doing all the latter procedure within the `AppDelegate` function `application(_ application: NSApplication, open urls: [URL])`.

From my limited understanding this is the way to handle this, but now
how can I get back from there to get hold of the current view? I am really struggling with the view controller life cycle part of things here I guess...

Comment: *click of a button in a ViewController* and *I am currently doing all of this within the AppDelegate* contradicts itself. Please add relevant code and elaborate what you are going to accomplish

Comment: Yeah sorry for being too vague, I tried to do a better job of explaining what my issue really is. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AppDelegate, you can get a reference to the current window's ViewController as follows. Replace "MainViewController" with the name of the one you use.

**iOS Swift:**

```
if let vc = window?.rootViewController as? MainViewController {
    // use `vc` here by calling public functions
    // and accessing public properties
}
```

**macOS Swift:**

```
if let vc = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow?.contentViewController as? MainViewController {
    // use `vc` here by calling public functions
    // and accessing public properties
}
```

Comment: Ooh boy, I feel so stupid: just now realise I didn't point out that I am asking for a macOS application -- and not for iOS.

Thats the only reason I cannot mark this answer as a solution -- but for iOS this definitely would be the way to go -- so thanks for your help!

Comment: Updated with macOS version.

Comment: Nice :-) Almost the way I've now done it (seems like we both wrote it simultaneously...

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it: since there is no rootViewController in macOS-land as there is with iOS, it works a little different:

in macOS you can get hold of the window currently "under keyboard" like so:

in `application(_:open:)`, where the `redirect_uri` gets called:

```
if let viewController = NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.contentViewController as? ViewController {
    // make changes to the view
}
```